# iOS Dropbox SDK Chunked upload of open file

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I'm trying to use chunked uploads to "stream" a video file up to Dropbox as it's being recorded.

I start the upload a few seconds after the video recording starts, in order to prevent the upload from ever catching up to the end of the video file.

When I stop recording before the chunked upload starts, everything works fine.

But if I stop recording after the upload starts, everything appears to work correctly, but the resulting movie file is corrupted.

Are chunked uploads of an open (and expanding) file not supported?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/204501535-Chunk-upload-of-expanding-file-on-iOS ]

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: The problem was that the video file format has a header segment which is written after the file is complete. So it is not possible to transmit the file in chunks because the header will be modified after it has been transmitted, resulting in a bad file.